# Aggregation in Django

Tags: django

I have the following Model in Django:

```
class A(models.Model):
    nr = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField()

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So for every A there are many entries in C, and for every B there are also many entries in C. But for every entry in C there is exactly one entry in A and one in B.

I would like to sum up the B.points for a given A, but I have to go over C.

How can I do that in Django? I would know how to do that in SQL if that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `A`s, like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

A.objects.annotate(
    total_points=Sum('c__b__points')
)
```

If you for example always want to annotate your `A` objects, you can define a manager for that:

```
class WithPointsManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            total_points=Sum('c__b__points')
        )
```

and then define this manager on the `A` class, like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    nr = models.IntegerField()

    objects = WithPointsManager()
```

So now if you perform an `A.objects.all()`, the `A`s will have a `total_points` attribute. Note that of course this will have a certain cost at the database side.

Then all `A` objects that arise from this `QuerySet`, will contain an extra `.total_points` attribute that contains the sum of all `B`s that are related to a `C` that is related to that `A`.

Or for a given `A` object, you can [**`.aggregate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

some_a.c_set.aggregate(
    total_points=Sum('b__points')
)['total_points']
```

This will return the sum of the `points` of related `B` objects of the set of `C`s that are related to `some_a`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The latter worked like a charm. Can you give me a hint where to make the annotation (the first way) - so that all the A's are affected, no matter which view is getting one?

Comment: @ataxis: you can override the `.objects` manager with a manager that performs this annotation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/

Comment: you are my today's hero :D thank you very much for your time